# How to create network interface programmatically?

Tags: c#

How can I add a network interface so that when I go to "My Network Places" to see "Local Area Connection" and the new added connection? I am referring to Windows XP.

Comment: Network interfaces are usually added by plugging additional network interface controllers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Network_card.jpg) into the PC. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you already said what i am trying to do :)

Comment: Then buy a NIC, plug it in, done. Windows will detect that new hardware has been added and create a new Local Area Connection accordingly. What's the problem?

Comment: Do you want an addtional physical network interface or do you want to have multiple IPs? Multiple IPs can be achieved by either adding new physical NIC or you can assign multiple IP to a single NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use netsh

---

**Netsh.exe** is a command-line scripting utility that allows you to, either locally or remotely, display or modify the network configuration of a computer that is currently running. Netsh.exe also provides a scripting feature that allows you to run a group of commands in batch mode against a specified computer. Netsh.exe can also save a configuration script in a text file for archival purposes or to help you configure other servers.

**Netsh.exe** is available on Windows 2000, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
```

> A more comprehensive list of cmd-line Networking-utilities in Windows.
>   [www.commandwindows.com/tcpiputil.htm](http://commandwindows.com/tcpiputil.htm)